# Don't inherit private member if it's accessed by public member

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm sorry if this question may be asked all the time, but I searched and couldn't find an sufficient answer.

**How to disable inheritance of private members/fields if they are being accessed by a public member/method?**

So consider this:

```
public class A {
    private MemberA a = new MemberA();

    public void foo(TypeA x) {
    a.methodCall(); //access to a
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private MemberB b = new MemberB();

    public void foo(TypeB x) {
    b.methodCall(); 
    }
}
```

If you hit the debugger you'll see, that B has a field a by type MemberA. That's in compliance with Java rules because if a public member has access to a private member it will be inherited.
But in B "a" is useless and only taking memory - even if you don't instanciate it in the constructor of B, because B calls it's super constructor and it has to be instanciated in A because a has very much use for a.

I *need* to have same method names for A and B and they have to be public, but since they do fundamentally different things but also share common logic B needs to be inherited from A.

So basically, I need to know how to overload and override a method the same time. Or duplicate code. What to do?

Comment: "If a public member has access to a private member it will be inherited". I don't know where you got this idea from. *All* members are inherited *always,* but access rules may affect visibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This situation -- where a class has data members that you do not want to inherit -- is called the ["Refused Bequest" antipattern](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/refused-bequest), and what it generally means is that your inheritance relationship is wrong. Rather than having B extend A, you need an interface C that both implement independently. If there is significant implementation that you *do* want to share, then perhaps you could introduce an abstract base class that A and B could share.

Comment: So I take the commonalities and sum them up in an abstract class. A and B have both their own foo but it won't get overloaded, right?

Comment: The methods could both be in the interface, if you needed them to be overloaded on both objects -- but it sounds like you don't need or want that.

Comment: I agree with Ernest _but_ I would say that you should think carefully before introducing the abstract base class. Does object B have an ISA relationship with Object A? If it does, then go ahead with the abstract class - otherwise take the common functionality out in to a helper class that they both can use. If you get this wrong, then you are still left with a poor inheritance relationship which is likely to bite you later on.

Comment: The ABC here can be package-private, so clients never even see it; they deal only with the interface. Using a helper class with delegation is fine too, though, as you say.

Comment: I decided to go the way Ernest recommended. I can choose to put `public void foo(X y)`into each subclass of abstract base class or I could force the subclasses to implement a method called foo but how do I do it?
I tried `abstract public <T> void foo(T x)` but when I implmenent foo in say A like this `public <TypeA> void foo(TypeA x)`it says <TypeA> is hiding TypeA. How to force subclasses to implement a method with a signature like `public void NAME([TYPE] x)`where [TYPE] can be what ever subclass wants it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, it could also be that MemberA and MemberB (*not A and B*) share the common interface (or abstract class), say "Member", including methodCall().  You could then do

```
public class A {
  protected Member myMember;  // sounds like an Austin Powers movie...

  // in the constructor
  myMember= new A();
}
```

while, in class B, the constructor does this instead:  (or use DI, etc...)

```
  myMember = new B();
```

and in `foo()`, which *need not be overloaded*, you call `myMember.methodCall()`.

Without knowing your problem it's hard to say if this approach or @Ernest's is better.  In either case you are looking for common functionality, and it will likely be the same amount of work.